# SetValue method doesn't work after DoubleAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, setvalue, doubleanimation

I have this code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Storyboard st_common = new Storyboard(); 
    DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation();         

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();               
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        anim1.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        anim1.From = 10.0;
        anim1.To = 100.0;
        st_common.Children.Add(anim1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(anim1, r1.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));
        st_common.Begin(this);

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        r1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 300.0);            
        r2.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 300.0);
    }
}
```

Why does `SetValue` method not work for r1 element after animation? (r1 and r2 are rectangles)

Comment: You have Button_Click() and Button_Click_1 which looks like possibly you have one of these event handlers no longer property connected to a button event? How many buttons are on the form? What is r1 and r2?

Comment: The c# tag tells everyone it's c#, plus it's more or less clear from the syntax. Fixed some punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storyboard animation is still holding the value at what the last animated value is. This is a known "feature", and there are three ways around it...

1. Set the animation FillBehavior to Stop
2. Remove the storyboard
3. Remove the entire animation.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx on how to peform these actions.

Comment: The first and third ways results that rectangle r1 come back to origin location that was before the animation. Second way does not affect. Any idea?